# Apply script only to first and second level categories WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hierarchical, taxonomy-terms

I need to add a script by functions php on different specific categories.

Example of 1 category: Car -> Bmw -> x1.(this is only a example, i have different categories hierarchy like this)

I need to apply this script only to category "car" and category "bmw", so first and second level category only.

How can i do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find 3 conditional functions that will allow you to check if a term is from:

- 1st level product category only
- 2nd level product category only
- 1st or 2nd level product category

All 3 conditional functions work with product category term Id, slug or name.

```
// Utility function:  Get the WP_Term object from term ID, slug or name
function wc_category_to_wp_term( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if( is_numeric( $term ) && term_exists( $term, $taxonomy ) ) {
        return get_term( (int) $term, $taxonomy );
    } elseif ( is_string( $term ) && term_exists( $term, $taxonomy ) ) {
        return get_term_by( 'slug', sanitize_title( $term ), $taxonomy );
    } elseif ( is_a( $term, 'WP_Term' ) && term_exists( $term->slug, $taxonomy ) ) {
        return $term;
    }
    return false;
}

// Conditional function to check if  if a product category is a top level term
function is_wc_cat_lvl_1( $category, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
    if( $term = wc_category_to_wp_term( $category, $taxonomy ) ) {
        return ( $term->parent === 0 ) ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}

// Conditional function to check if a product category is a second level term
function is_wc_cat_lvl_2( $category, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
    if( ( $term = wc_category_to_wp_term( $category, $taxonomy ) ) && $term->parent !== 0 ) {
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );

        // Loop through ancestors terms to get the 1st level term
        foreach( $ancestors as $parent_term_id ){
            // Get the 1st level category
            if ( get_term($parent_term_id, $taxonomy)->parent === 0 ) {
                $first_level_id = $parent_term_id;
                break; // stop the loop
            }
        }
        return isset($first_level_id) && $first_level_id === $term->parent ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}

// Conditional function to check if a product category is a first or second level term
function is_wc_cat_lvl_1_or_2( $category, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
    $lvl_1 = is_wc_cat_lvl_1( $category, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' );
    $lvl_2 = is_wc_cat_lvl_2( $category, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' );

    return $lvl_1 || $lvl_2 ? true : false;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE example** - Display if a product category term is from 1st or 2nd product category level:

```
$term1 = "Clothing"; // a 1st level category
$term2 = "Hoodies"; // a 2nd level category
$term3 = "Levis"; // a 3rd level category

echo  'Is "' . $term1 . '" a level 1 or 2 category: ' . ( is_wc_cat_lvl_1_or_2( $term1 ) ? 'YES' : 'NO' ) . '<br>'; 
echo  'Is "' . $term2 . '" a level 1 or 2 category: ' . ( is_wc_cat_lvl_1_or_2( $term2 ) ? 'YES' : 'NO' ) . '<br>';
echo  'Is "' . $term3 . '" a level 1 or 2 category: ' . ( is_wc_cat_lvl_1_or_2( $term3 ) ? 'YES' : 'NO' ) . '<br>';
```

This will output:

> Is "Clothing" a level 1 or 2 category: YES 
>   Is "Hoodies" a level 1 or 2 category: YES 
>   Is "Levis" a level 1 or 2 category: NO